# How to monitor ClamAV?

Tags: postfix, amavis, clamav

I have a postfix mailserver with amavis as a content_filter setup successfully an now I wonder how I can monitor if clamav is working properly. The clamav logfile is empty and I can not see any trace that it is working. I don't have any clue that it is not working, I just want to be sure that is working properly.

So how can I monitor and test ClamAV to verfiy that it is working properly?

Comment: try sending a "known-bad" email?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just send an email with the [eicar test file](http://www.eicar.org/anti_virus_test_file.htm) attached. This file has a signature which any virus scanner should know and detect.

As for the monitoring of the `clamd` process itself, there are many possibilities. I personally prefer using [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) for it.